# tika-app-1.7.jar vs tika-server-1.7.jar

Tags: java, server, apache-tika

I wrote a web service in java with using jersey framework that using my apache tika wrapper. That wrapper wraps tika-app-1.7.jar. My question what is the best way: wrap tika-app-1.7.jar or tika-server-1.7.jar or it doesn't matter?

Comment: If you're writing Java code, why do you need to be using either of the standalone jars to start with? Why not just call Tika directly from within java?

Comment: I wrote wrapper for tika jar because I need to create war file and deploy it on tomcat.

Comment: OK, but why use the Tika App or Tika Server jars as your base? Why not just add maven dependencies on the Tika Core and Tika Parsers modules, and have it all pulled in normally?

Comment: I think I have not enough knowledge for it in java. I never didn't work with maven and I don't know what is Tika Core/Parsers. I will read about it. Thank you.

Comment: Try the [Apache Tika examples](http://tika.apache.org/1.7/examples.html) as a good starting point, and/or get the Apache Tika book from Manning

Answer (score 3):

The Tika build consists of a number of components and produces the following main binaries:

- **tika-core/target/tika-core-*.jar**

  Tika core library. Contains the core interfaces and classes of Tika, but none of the parser implementations. Depends only on Java 6.
- **tika-parsers/target/tika-parsers-*.jar**

  Tika parsers. Collection of classes that implement the Tika Parser interface based on various external parser libraries.
- **tika-app/target/tika-app-*.jar**

  Tika application. Combines the above components and all the external parser libraries into a single runnable jar with a GUI and a command line interface.
- **tika-server/target/tika-server-*.jar**

  Tika JAX-RS REST application. This is a Jetty web server running Tika REST services as described in this page.
- **tika-bundle/target/tika-bundle-*.jar**

  Tika bundle. An OSGi bundle that combines tika-parsers with non-OSGified parser libraries to make them easy to deploy in an OSGi environment.

Answer (score 1):

Tika app is runnable ie.

You can pass commmand line parameters and get the results.

However Tika server runs as http server where you can send and receive http request/response.

Both uses tika core classes to do the job.

If you are writing a wrapper it doesn't matter as the server/commandline code simply never executed.